Puppet bolt run with sudo
I want to run a puppet bolt script with sudo. The problem is, if I elevate my user with '--run-as root' the script doesn't run as root, it still gives me a 'permission denied'. But if i try it with ssh manually, I can elevate to root and run the script.
Is it possible, to execute a puppet bolt script to sudo, without using the root user/password?
